# Text is not highlighted in Python IDLE when doing the Search or in case of invalid Syntax

Tags: python, python-idle

I am using Python IDLE (ver: 3.4.3)as my editor to write my scripts, however when I run my code the compiler says there is an "Invalid Syntax", but that invalid Syntax Text is not being highlighted.To narrow down if the issue is with the highlighting, I also tried searching some text using "Search"[Ctrl+F]and "Search and Replace"[Ctrl+H], and I found that even if there is a match; the corresponding text is not being highlighted. Interesting thing is that it was working yesterday, and today when I try, it is not working anymore.I even rebooted my machine,but no success. Please help.

Comment: Solution: don't use IDLE. It's not really suitable for anything other than playing around. Find a proper text editor, or even an IDE if you prefer.

Comment: I use Idle routinely to patch Idle and run other code and have had few problems with it.  There is, however, a bug on Windows with respect to marking found text that is a consequence of how tk and Windows behave.

Comment: I am puzzled by Syntax Error text not being highlighted as I have not seen that in 10 years.  Can you give an example?  If that is the thing that worked before and not now, then something changed either in your Python install or with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this appears to be a Windows problem, apparently with Tk.

http://bugs.python.org/issue14146

Found a hack:

    `(1) highlight text
    (2) Ctrl + f
    (3) Alt + F4
    i.e exit find window
    (4) Ctrl + g
    i.e. "find next"`

I used to find then it would highlight first match on exit, but then would have to repeat. This works well.

---------------------------- UPDATE: ---------------------------- 
Switched to "**real IDE**" - it was easy and worth it.
Many exist. I am using **VS Code** with **extensions** (*Ctrl+Shift+X*):
**CodeRunner** and **Python** 

1) Set syntax highlighting: (*File -> Preferences -> Theme*)

2) Manually configure Python extension:

  (i) (*File -> Preferences -> Theme*)

  (ii) overwrite: "python.pythonPath": "c:/python34/python.exe"

3) Set auto-save-run shortcut: (*Ctrl+Shift+B*)

  (i) (*Ctrl+Shift+P*) -> "configure task" -> *enter*

  (ii) replace task file with:

`{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    /*
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "echo",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["Hello World"],
    "showOutput": "always"
    */
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "python",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "args": ["${file}"]
}`

 Src: http://mahugh.com/2016/04/27/python-and-vs-code/

'VS' := visual studio